# How to test if the user's desktop is active in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

When a Qt desktop application is running on an inactive desktop, after switching to another user (via the OS's switch user feature), can this be detected in code?
I need to check for this condition because I need to disable some functionalities of my application if the desktop is not active.
If possible, I'd prefer a pure-Qt solution that works on Windows (>= Vista) and OS X (>= 10.6).

Comment: As of Qt 5.7, this is not possible without native code.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.6. I'm not against using native code, just like to avoid it when possible. If required, we still have #ifdef's and such...

Comment: Checking for the main window leaving focus might be enough

Comment: @paulm: can't use that approach. It's a systray application and main window is usually closed.

Comment: You'd have to do per OS native code instead as already mentioned then

Comment: I added that as a comment just as an FYI. I don't have a native solution, but figured knowing even the most current Qt version lacks such functionality would be helpful.

Comment: propably [session managment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/session.html)?

Comment: @paulm: John Harper's comment suggests that it would be possible with Qt < 5.7

Comment: Nope. Not what I meant. :-)

Comment: Found a solution on windows in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315013/how-to-get-the-active-user-when-multiple-users-are-logged-on-in-windows. For OS X this seems useful as well https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/UserSwitchNotifications.html

Comment: " comment suggests that it would be possible with Qt < 5.7" On the contrary. It suggests that it's not implemented in any version up to 5.7. Qt usually doesn't drop that sort of functionality between minor versions.