# A process created with CreateProcessAsUserW from a 64 bit process exits immediately with exception code 0xc06d007e on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7-x64, createprocessasuser

I have a  C# Application, which is launched from a C++ DLL using CreateProcessAsUserW api. The process is launched successfully, but terminates immediately. It works properly on Windows 10 [both as 32 bit and 64 bit] and 32 bit on Windows 7. I found the following link,

[Why is this process crashing as soon as it is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched)

however, process monitor from SysInternals finds no missing dll. [I can attach the saved logs from ProcMon] I also tried passing the path to the application folder, as suggested elsewhere, in the lpCurrentDirectory parameter of the API, but that did not work either.

I followed the guidance in [How to get the active user when multiple users are logged on in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315013/how-to-get-the-active-user-when-multiple-users-are-logged-on-in-windows) to write the code which launches the process,
and the method which launches the process is called from a windows service.To emulate that from the command line, I used the following
[How do you run CMD.exe under the Local System Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account) [psexec64 -i -s cmd.exe, and then launched the process from cmd.exe]
The method is as follows
//[How to get the active user when multiple users are logged on in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315013/how-to-get-the-active-user-when-multiple-users-are-logged-on-in-windows)

```
 STDMETHODIMP CProcessManager::LaunchProcessAsActiveUser(BSTR processName, LONG* dwProcessId)
    {

        //char *lpszPath = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(processName);
        wchar_t* path = (wchar_t*)processName;//CharToWideChar(lpszPath);

        DWORD session_id = -1;
        DWORD session_count = 0;

        WTS_SESSION_INFOA *pSession = NULL;


        if (WTSEnumerateSessionsA(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSession, &session_count))
        {
            //log success
        }
        else
        {
            //log error
            return S_OK;
        }
        logger->Log(L"Session Count", session_count);
        logger->Log(L"Begin Enumerating Sesions");
        for (int i = 0; i < session_count; i++)
        {
            session_id = pSession[i].SessionId;
            logger->Log(L"SessionId", session_id);

            WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS wts_connect_state = WTSDisconnected;
            WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS* ptr_wts_connect_state = NULL;

            DWORD bytes_returned = 0;
            if (::WTSQuerySessionInformation(
                WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                session_id,
                WTSConnectState,
                reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR*>(&ptr_wts_connect_state),
                &bytes_returned))
            {
                wts_connect_state = *ptr_wts_connect_state;
                ::WTSFreeMemory(ptr_wts_connect_state);
                if (wts_connect_state != WTSActive) continue;
            }
            else
            {
                //log error
                continue;
            }
            logger->Log(L"End Enumerating Sesions");
            logger->Log(L"Selected Session Id", session_id);
            HANDLE hImpersonationToken;

            if (!WTSQueryUserToken(session_id, &hImpersonationToken))
            {
                //log error
                logger->Log(L"Exception in WTSQueryUserToken", GetLastError());
                continue;
            }


            //Get real token from impersonation token
            DWORD neededSize1 = 0;
            HANDLE *realToken = new HANDLE;
            if (GetTokenInformation(hImpersonationToken, (::TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS) TokenLinkedToken, realToken, sizeof(HANDLE), &neededSize1))
            {
                CloseHandle(hImpersonationToken);
                hImpersonationToken = *realToken;
            }
            else
            {
                //log error
                logger->Log(L"Exception in GetTokenInformation", GetLastError());
                continue;
            }


            HANDLE hUserToken;

            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hImpersonationToken,
                //0,
                //MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
                TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS | MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
                NULL,
                SecurityImpersonation,
                TokenPrimary,
                &hUserToken))
            {
                //log error
                logger->Log(L"Exception in DuplicateTokenEx", GetLastError());
                continue;
            }

            // Get user name of this process
            //LPTSTR pUserName = NULL;
            WCHAR* pUserName;
            DWORD user_name_len = 0;

            if (WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, session_id, WTSUserName, &pUserName, &user_name_len))
            {
                //log username contained in pUserName WCHAR string
                // char * lpszUserName = WideCharToChar(pUserName);
                logger->Log(pUserName);
                //LocalFree(lpszUserName);
            }
            else
            {
                logger->Log(L"Exception in WTSQuerySessionInformation", GetLastError());
            }

            //Free memory                         
            if (pUserName) WTSFreeMemory(pUserName);

            ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hUserToken);

            STARTUPINFOW StartupInfo;

            StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);




            //GetStartupInfoW(&StartupInfo);
            ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
            //Uncommented  by Sagar 20th January 20118 1612
            StartupInfo.lpDesktop = CharToWideChar("winsta0\\default");

            //to Hide Console Process 03-10-2018
            StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
            StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;//SW_HIDE;



            PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;



            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security1;
            ZeroMemory(&Security1, sizeof(Security1));

            Security1.nLength = sizeof SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;


            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security2;
            ZeroMemory(&Security2, sizeof(Security2));
            Security2.nLength = sizeof SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;

            void* lpEnvironment = NULL;

            // Get all necessary environment variables of logged in user
            // to pass them to the new process
            BOOL resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpEnvironment, hUserToken, FALSE);

            if (!resultEnv)
            {
                //log error
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                logger->Log(L"Exception in CreateEnvironmentBlock", err);

                continue;
            }

            WCHAR PP[1024]; //path and parameters
            ZeroMemory(PP, 1024 * sizeof WCHAR);
            wcscpy_s(PP, path);
            wcscat_s(PP, L" ");
            //wcscat(PP, args);

            // Start the process on behalf of the current user 
            BOOL result = CreateProcessAsUserW(hUserToken,
                PP,
                NULL,
                &Security1,
                &Security2,
                FALSE,
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE/*| CREATE_NO_WINDOW*/,//CREATE_NO_WINDOW to Hide Console Process 03-10-2018
                /*lpEnvironment*/NULL,

                //"C:\\ProgramData\\some_dir",
                NULL,
                /*NULL,*/
                &StartupInfo,
                &processInfo);

            if (!result)
            {
                //log error
                //char * lpszPath = WideCharToChar(PP);
                logger->Log(L"Failed to create process", PP);
                //LocalFree(lpszPath);
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                logger->Log(L"GetLastError returned", err);

            }
            else
            {
                *dwProcessId = processInfo.dwProcessId;
                logger->Log(L"Created Process", *dwProcessId);
                //log success
            }

            DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);

            CloseHandle(hImpersonationToken);
            CloseHandle(hUserToken);
            CloseHandle(realToken);

            RevertToSelf();
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(pSession);


        return S_OK;
    }
```

Procmon screen shots attached below
Please help.
Thanks,
Sagar

```
[![Pg 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJCrG.png)
[![Pg 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo8Uw.png)
[![Pg 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7g12.png)
[![Pg 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e5w4.png)
[![Pg 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k2b0.png)
```

I tried the following permutations

```
Target Process : ATL DLL : Launcher:Result
 64 bit      64 bit     64 bit      Crashes
 64 bit      32 bit     64 bit      Crashes
 32 bit      32 bit     64 bit      Crashes
 32 bit      64 bit     64 bit      Crashes
 32 bit      32 bit     32 bit      OK
 64 bit      32 bit     32 bit      OK
 64 bit      64 bit     32 bit      OK
 32 bit      64 bit     32 bit      OK
```

So it seems that if the launcher process is 64 bit, it always crashes and if it is 32 bit, it always succeeds. What is the difference between a 64 and 32 bit launcher process?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your code? Why did you decide against providing a [mcve]?

Comment: Code on git hub : https://github.com/ks1974in/ConsoleLauncherApp.git. Sorry for not doing it earlier. And I also found that the same thing happens for 32 bit processes too.

Comment: Minimal code should be included directly in question, no one wants to dig through a complete github project to find the relevant code.

Comment: The c# process that is crashing is presumably your application? If so: do you have logging on? And you tried debugging it? (Visual Studio can be configured to start a debug session but wait to attach to a named process as soon as its launched iirc).

Comment: @ChrisBecke, I added an exception handler to the c# application, but it is not getting called. The error could be before the dot net code starts

Comment: 0xc06d00e only ever means one thing, the process you start *does* have a problem locating a DLL.  Exclusive to delay-loaded DLLs, a feature available to native code written in MSVC++.  You can see it go wrong with SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see the trace of the program searching for the DLL and not finding it.  Forgetting to set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory is an easy thing to get wrong in a "program launcher" app.

Comment: @HansPassant, I added screenshots of ProcMon logs. I could not find anything in them.

Comment: @HansPassant, the target process does not use any MSVC++ functionality. It is a pure dot net app. I have listed the permutations which work and which dont in a table in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb9d15fb-dc9f-488e-92c4-e0bb438442e1/64-bit-dot-net-process-created-with-createprocessasuserw-exits-immediately-with-exception-code?forum=vcgeneral [RLWA32 answered it]
There was a problem with the way in which the process was being launched. His code for launching the process is as follows, and it works fine.

```
UINT __stdcall RunProgram(LPVOID pv)
{
    WCHAR szTarg32[MAX_PATH] = TARGET32_PATH, szTarg64[MAX_PATH] = TARGET64_PATH;
    LPWSTR pszProcess = nullptr;
    PWTS_SESSION_INFOW pwsi = NULL;
    DWORD dwSession = -1, dwCount = 0;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment = nullptr;
    LPWSTR pszPath = nullptr;
    UINT ret = 1;


    DWORD dwOpcode = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(pv);

    if (dwOpcode == LAUNCH_X86PROCESS)
        pszProcess = szTarg32;
    else
        pszProcess = szTarg64;

    if (!WTSEnumerateSessionsW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, 0, 1, &pwsi, &dwCount))
    {
        Report(L"WTSEnumerateSessions failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        return ret;
    }

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
    {
        if (pwsi[i].State == WTSActive)
        {
            dwSession = pwsi[i].SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dwSession != -1)
    {
        if (WTSQueryUserToken(dwSession, &hToken))
        {
            if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpEnvironment, hToken, FALSE))
            {
                HRESULT hr;
                if (SUCCEEDED((hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, hToken, &pszPath))))
                {
                    if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken))
                    {
                        STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof si };
                        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

                        if (CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, pszProcess, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, pszPath, &si, &pi))
                        {
                            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                            Report(L"CreateProcessAsUser started %s, pid is %d\n", pszProcess, pi.dwProcessId);
                            ret = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            Report(L"CreateProcessAsUser failed with %d\n", GetLastError());

                        RevertToSelf();
                    }
                    else
                        Report(L"ImpersonateLoggedOnUser failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
                else
                    Report(L"SHGetKnownFolderPath failed with 0x%X\n", hr);
            }
            else
                Report(L"CreateEnvironmentBlock failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else
            Report(L"WTSQueryUserToken failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
        Report(L"WTSEnumerateSessions reported no active session\n");

    if (pwsi)
        WTSFreeMemory(pwsi);

    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);

    if (lpEnvironment)
        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);

    if (pszPath)
        CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);

    return ret;
}
```